# How to avoid fetching table definition by default when select tables in Oracle SQL Developer connections window

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer when i open the tree view of any database and see all tables into it, it automatically fetch the definitions of that selected table. So how can i avoid this feature when i select a table. My mean to simulate the functionality of SQL Server DB IDE where when we select a table it doesn't do specific to it but just to navigate.

Comment: Why would you want to select a table in the tree when you want nothing to happen?

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe I want to select a table and want to go further using arrow key by navigating these tables. In current scenario it is not happening smoothing because every time i press arrow key to go downward it make request to get it's definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Oracle DB IDE" - I am assuming you mean Oracle SQL Developer.

In Tools > Preferences

- Database
- Object Viewer
- Open Object on Single Click (uncheck!)

Now you can click on objects, and drag them to a worksheet or model, w/o having the object editor initialized. To open the object, you'll need to double-click on the tree items.

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith this solved the problem and i have also updated the question text by Oracle SQL Developer. :)

Comment: No problem @Himanshu - this is actually one of 4 preferences I recommend folks to change. See the other 3 here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/30-sql-developer-posts-in-30-days-day-29-preferences-revisited/

Comment: thanks once again @thatjeffsmith for sharing this article... actually i am very new to oracle and worked previously on sql server which was very easy to use and navigate as per my experience that why it was frustrating while doing navigation through objects in oracle sql developer unlike sql server...

Comment: Learning the tool won't be too bad, there are many similarities to SSMS. Same with the database as well - but don't take things for granted!

Comment: sure Jeff i will remember this... :)